# How to configure entity tags (ETags) on IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, etags

YSlow is complaining about some images with misconfigured ETags, I found some articles and followed the instructions, but it is still not working for me in IIS 8.5

**Any idea what is the right way to ADD eTags or how to add a Rewrite Rule that can do it?**

For example, YSlow on https://UFOToday.com

[image]

Comment: Please define "how to do that". Do you need to add, remove or reconfigure Etag headers? Here are some examples to remove the Etag header: https://www.saotn.org/remove-etags-http-header-iis/ , but you might require them if your hosting environment relies on etag headers.

Comment: I'm adding ?v=1 manually - maybe that's causing the problem?